# Making Chrome Extension Installer In NSIS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, installation, nsis

```
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "7.0.0"
!define CRXNAME "1.crx"
!define CRXID "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
!define INSTALL_DIR "$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\${CRXID}\${PRODUCT_VERSION}_0"
!define P_FILE "$LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"

Function .onInit
SetSilent silent
FunctionEnd
```

Folder Is Getting Created But its Blank.
Empty Folder Without my .crx files.

my .crx is in same directory.

I want this installer to add extension to chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `File` instruction places files in the path set by `SetOutPath`, try:

```
Section
SetOutPath "${INSTALL_DIR}"
File "${CRXNAME}"  
...
SectionEnd
```

You can also set the $instdir variable with `InstallDir "${INSTALL_DIR}"`

Comment: My extension isn't getting listed in chrome://extensions/